# Accessing local filesystem from jQuery and Chrome?

Tags: jquery, html, file-io

I have an html page that is generated by some other application and links together a bunch of images on the file system.  This html5 file is NOT served up by a webserver, it's just local.

Currently, it is using ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") to allow me to look for directories/files on the the filesystem depending on some user input, but of course it is dependent on IE.

Is there something equivalent in jQuery that would allow me to have the same or similar functionality but be a bit more browser independent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.  This article explains that JavaScript file access is not allowed due to potential malicious usage from websites: [Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript).  JQuery is built upon JavaScript, so the same should be true.

Comment: Ah, interesting read thanks.  Kind of a bummer.  It makes me wonder though... instead of ActiveX maybe there is some other package I could use that is browser independent as well?  It doesn't have to be javascript based at all.  I just want chrome/firefox users to be able to work with this html.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of a technology that would allow a browser-independent access to the client files.  As you have mentioned the individual browsers could have Plugins/ActiveX/etc., but those would not work across all browsers.